# How to make ISNULL not just return true or false

Tags: sql, sql-server, isnull, sql-server-ce-3.5

I am using SQL Server Compact Edition as  database for my Windows Application. I am having a problem while using `ISNULL`. I wrote a query

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL(MAX(TransactionID) + 1, 100) AS TransactionId 
FROM
    TBLTransactionMain
```

But this query returns only true or false. Is there anything I can do to get the same result as in SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use coalesce http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174075.aspx

The syntax is the same as the isnull.

Answer (score 0):

The question is somewhat vague, but if your goal is to assume a value if TransactionID is NULL, then something like this is what you need:

```
MAX( ISNULL( TransactionId, 0 ) + 1, 100 ) AS TransactionId
```

Otherwise, you may need to clarify.